# Why is `reserve` restricted for locked balances?

Tags: balances, transfer, reserved-balance, locked-balance, free-balance

I read the answer of Shawn about locked and reserved balances. [What is the difference between Free Balance, Reserved Balance, Locked Balance, Vesting Balance, etc...?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-is-the-difference-between-free-balance-reserved-balance-locked-balance-v)

He pointed out, that locked funds (`WithdrawReasons::TRANSFER`) can still be reserved.

> So if an account has a lock for 100 units with WithdrawReasons::Transfer, it cannot make a transfer which brings its free balance lower than 100 units. However, this account will be able to perform another operation like reserve taking its free balance below 100 units.

I tried this, but `pallet_balances` returns the `LiquidityRestrictions` error when I try to reserve locked funds.

https://crates.parity.io/src/pallet_balances/lib.rs.html#1445

Shouldn't be a reserve allowed while having it locked at the same time or is it correct as it is?

I mean the `free_balance` after a lock is still untouched. This could indicate that a `reserve` can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found 'you can reserve the lock funds' from the link you provide.

I'm not the author of pallet-balances. So, I don't know why it is designed like this.

But I can answer why you can not do this.

First, let's look at the [`AccountData`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1399afdcd8ab4d7fad149c96f9cadcaf04b94f86/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L672-L695) struct.

The free balance does not include the reserved balance. They are separated parts.

Then, the [`set_lock`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1399afdcd8ab4d7fad149c96f9cadcaf04b94f86/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L2117-L2137) and [`update_locks`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1399afdcd8ab4d7fad149c96f9cadcaf04b94f86/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L944-L994). Apparently, it doesn't care about the amount, just set a lock on the account.

And when you want to spend the fund, you will enter the [`ensure_can_withdraw`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1399afdcd8ab4d7fad149c96f9cadcaf04b94f86/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L1452-L1472) and [`frozen`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L702-L710). That's the point, it only interacts with free balance. It doesn't work with reserve.

For the [`reserve`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1399afdcd8ab4d7fad149c96f9cadcaf04b94f86/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L1763-L1781). You can see it also call the `ensure_can_withdraw`. So, you can not call reserve after lock.

Finally, we get:

```
free + reserved = total
free - lock     = usable

sometimes, the lock might be greater than the total

so, this pallet allows you to write your own logic like

set a lock depending on your reserve amount, and it might looks
like your locked funds were in reseved?
```

Comment: I meant this sentence of Shawn: 
`However, this account will be able to perform another operation like reserve taking its free balance below 100 units.`